# Artifactory upgrade

Tags: npm, artifactory

Since our last upgrade of artifactory (to the newest version) we see a lot of logs like this:

```
2018-04-23 08:10:36,429 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
2018-04-23 08:10:36,430 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
2018-04-23 08:10:36,439 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
2018-04-23 08:10:36,441 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
2018-04-23 08:10:36,442 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
2018-04-23 08:10:36,445 [http-nio-8081-exec-250] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:433) - npm-registry: Error in getting information for '_external/import-module-import-module' (null).
```

What does it mean and how can we fix them?

Answer (score 0):

This might be (As I don't have all of the details) an offline mode of the remote repository. This can happen usually when there a network issue that prevents Artifactory from reaching the remote site. If you can verify that the network is working properly and that you can reach the remote site from the Artifactory machine, you can edit your NPM remote repository, mark it as 'offline' save, edit again, uncheck the 'offline' and save again. 
This will take the repository out from the auto offline mode. 
The reason that Artifactory is getting to this state, as explained above, if to make sure that in case the remote site is unreachable, not to have a lot timeout on remote requests waiting for unreachable remote site.